# Automatic Third Party Libraries Acknowledgements and Licences added with Swift Package Manager

Tags: ios, swift, swift-package-manager

I am using the [Swift Package Manger (SPM)](https://swift.org/package-manager/) to add third party libraries to my iOS application. I would like to display acknowledgements and their respected licences. In the old [CocoaPod](https://cocoapods.org/) days this was possible with several libraries (e.g. [this one](https://github.com/carloe/LicenseGenerator-iOS)). Is there a way to achieve the similar things with SPM?

I am looking for

1. An automated solution which generates licence information when a new dependencies is added/removed via SPM.
2. Offers a `UIViewController` or `Settings.bundle` where the licences are displayed.

This doesn't have to be a library but can also be a build script. Item 2 could also be done by myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found a great Library called [LicensePlist](https://github.com/mono0926/LicensePlist), which does exactly what you asked for. The SPM support is still a bit lacking, however check out their GitHub Page for the exact installation instructions.

You [create a settings bundle](https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/adding-settings-to-your-ios-app-cecef8c5497) and add a Build Phase (explained on the LicensePlist Github Page). The library generates a `.plist` file for each library in your Settings Bundle and also generates a file that automatically adds a submenu in the in-app settings where all the Licenses are listed by name.